# Issues with Android Studio Room Type Converter

Tags: java, android

For some reason, I am having issues with the typeconverter in Android Studios. I have tried a variety of solutions from other posts, but continue to get this error. When I tried Arraylist of strings, instead of ingredients, the typeconverter does work.

`error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.`

```
@Entity(tableName = "Recipes")
    public class recipesDB {
        @PrimaryKey
        @NonNull
        @ColumnInfo(name = "recipeID")
        private int id;

    //Foreign Key to be used from Ingredients
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "url")
    private String url;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "readyInMinutes")
    private int readyInMinutes;

//Issue Here
@ColumnInfo(name = "ingredients")
private ArrayList<ingredient> ingredients;
```

DataConverter class:

```
public class DataConverter{


    @TypeConverter
    public static ArrayList<ingredient> toIngredient(String s){
        if(s == null){
            return null;
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ingredient>>(){}.getType();
        ArrayList<ingredient> ingredients = gson.fromJson(s, listType);
        return ingredients;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String getIngredients(ArrayList<ingredient> ingredients){
        if(ingredients == null){
            return null;
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ingredient>>() {}.getType();
        String json = gson.toJson(ingredients);
        return json;
    }
```

**EDIT**
AppDatabase:

```
@Database(entities = {recipesDB.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters({DataConverter.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;
    public abstract recipesDAO recipesdao();
    //public abstract pantryDAO pantrydao();
    public static AppDatabase getInMemoryDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class).build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    public static void destroyInstance(){INSTANCE = null;}
}
```

Comment: Did you add it to your DB with the corresponding annotation `@TypeConverters({YourDataConverter.class})` ?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Yes I did

Comment: it seems like your TypeConverter is not being used, can you paste your Room DB abstract class? Also please rename `ingredient` to `Ingredient` (it makes Java/Kotlin easier to read; by convention, types should start with UpperCase and follow CamelCase) :)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini So I think the refactoring fixed the problem. I am unable to fully test it at the moment, but I think it worked. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER** Turns out that renaming `ingredient` to `Ingredient` solved the problem (??) so… maybe keep an eye on those Class names and follow the Java convention of `ClassNamesStartWithUpperCase`.

**OLD ANSWER:**

I think, you may need to create a separate “entity” for your `ingredient` (just like `recipesDB` is).

Then `ingredient` sets up a `@ForeignKey` back to `recipesDB`.

And finally, you can add a *POJO* to have both `recipesDB` and `ArrayList<Ingredient>`.

I don’t have a sample here with me, but I’ve seen a bunch online.

I think the problem is that your “Converter” doesn’t know how to convert an “Ingredient”. It knows how to convert a `List<Ingredient>` though, but it’s not the same thing. ;)

Comment: Refactoring the name of my class from ingredient -> Ingredient solved the issue. Can't really explain why, but your suggestion to fixing my file name helped.

Comment: Well then maybe I was wrong! :) Glad to hear it worked. I’ll update the answer for future readers.

Comment: Can you mark the answer as the correct one please @JDoe?

Answer (score 1):

So the reason for the issue was due to a duplicate ingredient class outside the scope of my current folder directory. By changing the class ingredient to Ingredient, it must have cleared up the confusion for Room.